# How do I stop people from entering numbers in a popup on Netbeans v8

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, popup

[This picture is all my code for the pop-ups I currently have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA0iB.png)

I want to make it so that when a user goes to enter their name (If they want, if not it defaults to Player 1/ Player 2) and they enter a number instead, it will give another pop-up saying they can't put in a number.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a JTextField in the JOptionPane. Essentially, you'll need to create a JTextField, add a `KeyListener` to the field, and show a `messageDialog` with the field. If we use an `inputDialog`, two fields will show. I have developed the code below.

```
    JTextField field = new JTextField("Player 1 Name"); //Create a new JTextField with the text "Player 1 Name"
    field.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() { //Add a KeyListener
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { //Called when key is pressed
            String input = Character.toString(e.getKeyChar()); //Create string input which is equal to the key pressed
            if(input.equals("1") || input.equals("2") || input.equals("3") || input.equals("4") || input.equals("5") || input.equals("6") || input.equals("7") || input.equals("8") || input.equals("9") || input.equals("0")){ //If the string equals any number
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Numbers are not allowed!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); //Show a message dialog notifying the user
                field.setText(field.getText().substring(0, field.getText().length() - 1)); //Eliminate the number inputed
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    });
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, field, "Player Name", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE) //Show MessageDialog with the input field as the JTextField
```

You may use the same JTextField for all the dialogs so you won't have to copy the code twice. Hope this helped!